# OpenGL object & camera resistance?

Tags: opengl, object, camera, glut, lag

I'm developing a ***very*** basic came In C++ with openGL and GLUT where you move the "camera" around as the player.

## In short:

My camera slows down when I look at a snowman

## Full explanation:

Everything was fine until I decided to finally add in an object (a giant snowman in fact), but now I've added it, I'm experiencing very odd behaviour.

If I look at the snowman object and attempt to move forward, It feels like I'm moving against a force, as if I was walking through mud.

Now If I face opposite the snowman, and "walk" backwards with the camera, It moves completely fine, but when I look at it... I slow down. I've tried different scales of the snowman, and the larger the snowman is, the further I can feel the effect.

Note though, It doesn't appear to cause me to lag, only slow down.

Any insights would be greatly appreciated, and I will post code if needed, but currently.. I have no idea what code would be relevant!

Comment: Sounds like you might be encountering the [parallax effect](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Parallax).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When you say it slows down, you mean your frame rate drops? Sounds like your snowman is very polygon heavy, when it's being rendered it causes a drop in frame rate slowing things down.

When you're facing away from the snowman it's being clipped, it's not in view so the polygons comprising the model aren't being sent all the way through the 3D pipeline.

If you don't have back face culling turned on, you'll probably want to do that — otherwise you probably need to simplify the model somewhat. What happens if you render a cube there instead?

Depending on what hardware you're using, even a low poly model could cause problems if you don't have a huge fill rate (the speed of the hardware to fill pixels in the render buffer), but given that it's one model and that the hardware should be more than capable of filling the screen once, I'd say this is an unlikely scenario.

Comment: Yeah that would probably be it. I designed the snowman in a program called GLRex, which was like a primitive editor. Even if I make the snowman quite small, there is still some element of sluggishness :(. I tried with a huge hollow cube and it didn't slow down at all. Got any tips of ways I could maybe cut down on the poly's but keep original snowman? thank you!

Comment: It would depend on what GLRex offers, I've never come across it but it should allow you to specify parameters for the primitives relating to the number of subdivisions etc.. Turn all the numbers down so that it looks acceptable but isn't made of thousands of polygons :)

Comment: Well unfortunately, as GLRex is a simple shape editor created by an individual and only offers shape, size and NURB options :(. Thanks for your help anyway, was very useful.

Comment: Maybe have a look at using GLUT - that lets you generate primitives in code on the fly. Or of course, just find another modeller :)

Comment: Just and update: all the slowdown was caused by spheres. even if I had the smallest sphere in the program, it would slow down to some extent, but using glutSolidCube() for everything, it can be as large as I want and doesn't slow down. Weird stuff!

Comment: I suspect those spheres are calculated using curves or something, when the graphics hardware has to render them it'll do tessellation and approximate the shape with triangles. Sounds like it was creating a serious amount of triangles!